# What does "turned up halfway" exactly mean?

Tags: vocabulary

What does "turned up halfway" exactly mean?
For example

> Why is the heating often suddenly turned up
>   halfway through a flight?

Comment: Your example sentence should read: *Why is the heating often (suddenly turned up) (halfway through a flight)?*

Comment: In this context, "halfway" is probably used as a very imprecise estimate, just as "in the middle of the night" is much less precise than "12:00AM midnight".

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question as asked, *turned up halfway* means either "set to the middle of its range" or "moved (upward) half the remaining distance to the maximum setting".  If you have a heater that can be set from 0 to 10, and it is currently set at 5, then it is already "turned up halfway".  If, on the other hand, it is currently set at 2, and you receive a request to "turn it halfway up", then you should set it to 6 (that being the midpoint between 2 and 10).  (You could reasonably also set it to 5, the midpoint of its total range.)

To explain the example sentence, though, as @Damkerng points out, you need to parse it differently: "Why is it that often, halfway through a flight, the heating is suddenly turned up?"  And the answer to that is probably something like "that's when passengers seated next to windows start to complain about getting cold."